# Conditionally call function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a function called as Truncate that is truncating the text. How can i conditionally call that function only when offsetheight of left div with class demo exceeds the offsetheight of right div. If the condition is not met, then just return the original content.

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgpxve?editors=1111)

```js
var textHolder = document.querySelector('.demo');
var textHolder2 = document.querySelector('.demo2')
var textHolderHeight = textHolder.offsetHeight + 'px'
var textHolderHeight2 = textHolder2.offsetHeight + 'px'
console.log(textHolderHeight)
console.log(textHolderHeight2)
var fullText = textHolder.innerHTML;
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var textStatus = 'full'; // use this to check the status of text and toggle;

function Truncate(textHolder, limit) {
  let txt = textHolder.innerHTML;
  if (txt.length > limit) {
    let newText = txt.substr(0, limit) + ' ...';
    textHolder.innerHTML = newText;
    textStatus = 'truncated';
  }
}

Truncate(textHolder, textHolder.offsetWidth / 10);

function toggleText() {
  // here i want to show full text...
  // and also -> btn.innerHTML = 'Hide Text' | 'Show Text;
  if (textStatus === 'truncated') {
    textHolder.innerHTML = fullText;
    textStatus = 'full';
  } else {
    Truncate(textHolder, textHolder.offsetWidth / 10);
  }
}


btn.addEventListener('click', toggleText);
```

```html
<section class="demo" id="demo">
  Let's truncate a long line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course! Let's truncate a long line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course! Let's truncate a long
  line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course!
</section>

<button class="readMore btn">Read More</button>
<br><br><br>

<section class="demo2" id="demo2">
  Let's truncate a long line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course! Let's truncate a long line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course! Let's truncate a long
  line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course!don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course! Let's truncate a long line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to.
  Multi-line of course!don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course! Let's truncate a long line of text so that the words don't wrap when they're not supposed to. Multi-line of course!
</section>
```

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: You can use the if condition to call your function. If your condition satisfies then the function will be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use an if statement every time you need to call `Truncate`.

```
if(textHolderHeight > textHolderHeight2){
     Truncate(textHolder, textHolder.offsetWidth / 10);
}
```

Or put the code inside Truncate so you don't have to duplicate the if statements.

```
function Truncate(textHolder, limit) {
  let txt = textHolder.innerHTML;
  if (txt.length > limit && textHolderHeight > textHolderHeight2) {
    let newText = txt.substr(0, limit) + ' ...';
    textHolder.innerHTML = newText;
    textStatus = 'truncated';
  }
}
```